# Getting 401 error in Linkedin search Api

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am getting error 401 when i trying to use the search api(http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:) provided by the Linkedin. I am successfully able to login in Linkedin by using oauth2 rest api.
Have anyone an idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like LinkedIn is no longer keeping this API call (https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition):

> API availability
>   After the grace period expires, several REST API endpoints will no longer be available for general use.  The following endpoints are the only ones that will remain available for use:
>
> - Profile API — /v1/people/~
> - Share API — /v1/people/~/shares
> - Companies API — /v1/companies/{id}

Here you will find the valid API calls https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin

If your code has the properly auth you could use it:

> Once you have obtained a valid access token for the user, you can use the following REST API call to retrieve basic profile data for the user:
>
> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json

I hope this can help you.